# Change value of dynamically added js object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jsobject

I have an array with some predefined data

```
var data = [
    {amount:20, speed:100},
    {amount:40, speed:50}
];
```

I am then adding data to the above array

```
function addMore() {
    data = appendObjTo(data, {amount: 1500,speed:100});
}

function appendObjTo(thatArray, newObj) {
    const frozenObj = Object.freeze(newObj);
    return Object.freeze(thatArray.concat(frozenObj));
}
```

The data is being added fine, but for some reason, i am unable to change the value of the new data

```
function runData() {
    perSec = 0;
    $.each(data, function( key, value ) {
        perSecCalc = Math.round(value.speed/60);
        perSec += perSecCalc;
        // Below line works only for predefined objects, but not objects from "addMore()"
        data[key].amount = value.amount-perSec;
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        runData();
    },1000);
}
```

While the predefined object in "var data" is being changed, the dynamically added data from "addMore" does not change.

How come the new data is not changing ?

**Update**:
See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/616184/)

Comment: could you show the appendObjTo code?

Comment: Please look here: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/616184/

Comment: youre only calling `addMore` once?

Comment: Yes in this test example i am, but eventually it will be called whenever new data is present

Comment: why are you using `freeze`?

Comment: if youre just defining ```function appendObjTo(thatArray, newObj) {

 return thatArray.concat(newObj);
}``` it works

Comment: Ah yes of course. Thank you very much. Could you leave it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Object.freeze in your `appendObjTo` function. The definition of Object.freeze - [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

Since the frozenObj is created using `Object.freeze()`, the values are not allowed to change. Also, you are not getting any error on console. JS doesn't show error w/o strict mode enabled. I have modified the fiddle to include strict mode, and you can see that it throws and error when you do `data[key].amount = value.amount-perSec;`. I have also attached a fiddle to play with the Object.freeze() method, and you can experiment by yourself.

[Modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jforcode/xpvt214o/616382/)

JS

```
(function () {

"use strict";

var data = [
    {amount:20, speed:100}
];


function runData() {
    var perSec = 0;
    $.each(data, function( key, value ) {
        var perSecCalc = Math.round(value.speed/60);
        perSec += perSecCalc;
        // Below line works only for predefined objects, but not objects from "addMore()"
        data[key].amount = value.amount-perSec;
        $('#test').prepend(data[key].amount+'<br>');
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        runData();
    },1000);
}

function appendObjTo(thatArray, newObj) {
  const frozenObj = Object.freeze(newObj);
  return Object.freeze(thatArray.concat(frozenObj));
}

function addMore() {
    data = appendObjTo(data, {amount: 1500,speed:100});
}

setTimeout(function() { addMore(); },1500);

runData();


})();
```

[Object.freeze fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jforcode/xpvt214o/616352/)

```
var arr = [10, 20, 30];
console.log(arr);

arr = Object.freeze(arr.concat([40, 50]));
console.log(arr);

arr[3] = 80;
console.log(arr); // doesn't change

// arr.push(60); // error, cannot add property 5, object is not extensible

arr = Object.freeze(arr.concat([{ x: 100 }]));
console.log(arr);

arr[5].x = 200;
console.log(arr); // changes, as Object.freeze only locks the first level values.
```